# Very basic web server in C#

Tags: c#, server, desktop

I'm wanting to run a little socket server in C# to be accessed by a browser. I have a socket listener up and running on a specific port, and am trying to access it via the browser:

```
class WebSocketServer
{
    private static string output = string.Empty;

    public void CreateListener()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = null;
        var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        try
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 1313);
            tcpListener.Start();
            output = "Waiting for a connection";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        var socketHelper = new SocketHelper();
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);

            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            socketHelper.ProcessMessage(tcpClient, stream, bytes);
        }
    }
}

class SocketHelper
{
    private static int counter = 0;
    public void ProcessMessage(TcpClient tcpClient, NetworkStream stream, byte[] bytesReceived)
    {
        // handle message received and send response to client
        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived);
        string response = string.Empty;

        if (msg.Substring(0, 10) == "GET / HTTP")
        {
            response = "";// html page
        }

        byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
        stream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    }
```

The browser appears to connect to it, but it never seems to display the html - what's wrong? I'm eventually wanting to be able to serve up JSON data via a REST interface. In addition, is there a much easier solution to (I assume) this common problem.

Comment: You should use an `HttpListener` instead, it does most of the work for you

Comment: Is there additional code setting `string response` to something other than an empty string? If not, what are you expecting to see in the browser?

Comment: @KooKiz thanks - that'll do the trick!